# Running a .jar File Using .bat File

Tags: java, batch-file

HI Guys I Have A jar File Named Column Reader. I am trying to Run it using a .bat file that has the Following Script:

```
@echo off
java.exe -jar Column Reader.jar parameter
```

Can Anyone tell me why it is not Running? Because I have Managed t Run Another Jar File Named Nope.jar the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you have a space in the file name. Try instead with:

```
java.exe -jar "Column Reader.jar" parameter
```

Or better still, rename your JAR file to `column-reader.jar`. Generally JAR files are named in all lowercase, often without any spaces in the file names.

Some examples of proper JAR file names:

```
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas.jar
slf4j-api.jar
soap.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the command line knows where `java.exe`, and `Column Reader.jar` are. Also, you need to put anything that goes together in quotes, so it would be `"Column Reader.jar"`. You may need to point directly to the jar like this:

`java -jar "C:\Your\directory\Column Reader.jar" parameter`

To avoid the quotes you can just make sure the path doesn't contain any spaces. Also, if you want to point to a specific java.exe file you can do:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Your\directory\column-reader.jar parameter`

You don't have to be so explicit if your environment variable for java ([JAVA_HOME](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF26/Set+JAVA_HOME+variable+in+Windows)) is set and if your `.bat` file is in the same directory as your `.jar`